# Using git2go clone on CloudRun

Tags: git, go, libgit2, google-source-repositories

I'm trying to use https://github.com/libgit2/git2go for cloning repository from GCP Source repository

But, I'm getting `failed to resolve path '/tmp/repo/.git/': No such file or directory"`

By using gcloud source repo clone, it works.

```golang
func initRepo(url, path, auth string) (*git.Repository, error) {
    var repo *git.Repository
    var err error
    osPath := "/tmp/" + path

    repo, err = git.OpenRepository(osPath)
    if err != nil {
        repo, err = git.Clone(url, osPath, &git.CloneOptions{
            FetchOptions: &git.FetchOptions{
                Headers: []string{auth},
            },
        })
    }
    return repo, err
}

func main() {
    ctx := context.Background() 
    ts, err := google.DefaultTokenSource(ctx, sourcerepo.SourceFullControlScope)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    token, err := ts.Token()
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    auth := "Authorization: " + token.Type() + " " + token.AccessToken

    gitRepo, err := initRepo("https://source.developers.google.com/p/project/r/repo", "repo", auth)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
```

What can cause this error? Running on local machine it works, even in my docker container.

Comment: Do you have "strange" logs on Cloud logging?

Comment: nothing else except that error

Answer (score 1):

I'm betting my buck on the git2go library you're using not being capable of creating a directory at `/tmp/repo/.git/`. Make sure to mkdir the `/tmp/repo` first yourself maybe? Maybe `/tmp` doesn't exist?

Comment: I tried create `/tmp/repo` myself. That some thing. `/tmp` exists. Also before checking that error I read directory `/tmp/repo` and I can see there is `.git` folder inside. Even though it's empty.

Why it should not be able of creating directory? When inside my docker container `/tmp/repo` doesnt's exists, only `/tmp` and it is working